# How does wilcox.test() handle ties?

Tags: r, statistics, pairwise.wilcox.test

I run the pairwise.wilcox.test() on a data with many ties, I get the following warning:

```
Warning in wilcox.test.default(xi, xj, paired = paired, ...) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

I would like to know how does wilcox.test() handle the ties?

What method is used (by default) to rank the observations?

What does "P value adjustment method: holm" mean?

Answer (score 1):

When there are ties, `wilcox.test` uses a Normal approximation. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R#L335-L353): here is a slightly simplified version.

```r
## example values
x <- 1:5
y <- 2:6
## assumes mu=0
r <- c(x, y)
## slightly simplified (assumes `digits.rank` is equal to its default `Inf` value)
r <- rank(r)
NTIES <- table(r)
n.x <- length(x)
n.y <- length(y)
STATISTIC <- c("W" = sum(r[seq_along(x)]) - n.x * (n.x + 1) / 2)
z <- STATISTIC - n.x * n.y / 2
SIGMA <- sqrt((n.x * n.y / 12) *
            ((n.x + n.y + 1)
             - sum(NTIES^3 - NTIES) ## this will be zero in the absence of ties
                           / ((n.x + n.y) * (n.x + n.y - 1))))
## stuff about continuity correction omitted here
z <- z/SIGMA ## z-score, used to compute p-value
2*pnorm(z)  ## 2-tailed p-value (skipped testing whether in lower or upper tail)
```

This gives the same p-value as `wilcox.test(x, y, correct = FALSE)`.

As for p-value adjustment ("holm"), this points you to the help page for `?p.adjust`, which says that it is using the method from Holm (1979). You can find out more about the method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) (for example).

Holm, S. (1979).  A simple sequentially rejective multiple test
procedure.  *Scandinavian Journal of Statistics*, *6*, 65-70.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/4615733.